# Remotely locking computers for OSD via powershell, DOS, Task Sequence etc

Tags: powershell, sccm

I'm looking to get the best way to lock computers remotely. I have not been able to get these three to work. Even when I psexec to a machine these lock screen commands does not seem to work and I get no errors. I can do other psexec commands just not locking the current user. Reason why I need this is for OSD via sccm in-place-upgrade with multiple-language. The process is to change UI language to US, reboot and autologon with the created user account, and at some point after the log in, the lock screen should kick in to prevent end-users from fooling around with the OSD created users.

```
powershell.exe Invoke-Command -ComputerName $env:COMPUTERNAME -ScriptBlock { rundll32.exe user32.dll,LockWorkStation} -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue

cmd.exe /c %windir%\system32\rundll32.exe user32.dll,LockWorkStation

powershe.exe Stop-Process -Name WinLogon -Force
```

Any pointers is greatly appreciated.

Comment: I think your shell needs an interactive session which can be locked. How do you run the script? E.g. if its executed by SCCM, it'll run as SYSTEM without an interactive session. A scheduled task that runs in the context of the current user on logon as trigger should work.

Comment: I tried interactive and it didn't work. Although, I just created a bat file and scheduled task to trigger and it does work. I'm going to just try creating a bat file and see if this will work without creating a task sequence. So much involvement and it helps to ask someone to just give myself some time to think.